# Создание бота на c# со скачиванием видео на ютуб

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Написал бота на c# через long polling. Он должен скачивать видео по ссылкам от пользователей, но есть одна проблема. Когда один пользователь кидает ссылку боту, то тот перестает реагировать на сообщения от пользователей, пока не скачает и не отправит видео. Не понимаю как заставить его скачивать видео и продолжать обрабатывать сообщения. Возможно дело в том, что я использую long polling, а надо использовать веб хуки?

Вот пример кода:

1. Класс бота:

   using Telegram.Bot;
   using Telegram.Bot.Exceptions;
   using Telegram.Bot.Polling;
   using Telegram.Bot.Types;
   using Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums;

   namespace TestTgBot;

   public class TgBotService
   {
   private readonly ITelegramBotClient _bot;
   private readonly MessageHandler _messageHandler;
   private readonly MediaDownloader _mediaDownloader;

   ```
    public TgBotService(ITelegramBotClient client, MessageHandler messageHandler, MediaDownloader mediaDownloader)
    {
        _bot = client;
        _messageHandler = messageHandler;
        _mediaDownloader = mediaDownloader;
    }

    public async Task StartBot()
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var cancellationToken = cts.Token;
        var receiverOptions = new ReceiverOptions
        {
            AllowedUpdates = Array.Empty<UpdateType>()
        };

        var me = await _bot.GetMeAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, World! Че хуила? Документацию читаешь? Твой айди - {me.Id}, а имя {me.Username}");

        _bot.StartReceiving(
            updateHandler: HandleUpdateAsync,
            pollingErrorHandler: HandleErrorAsync,
            receiverOptions: receiverOptions,
            cancellationToken: cancellationToken
        );
    }

    private async Task HandleUpdateAsync(ITelegramBotClient bot, Update update, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (update.Message is not {} message)
            return;
        if (message.Text is not {} messageText)
            return;

        var chatId = message.Chat.Id;

        Console.WriteLine($"Получил весточку '{messageText}' от хуилы {chatId}.");

        _messageHandler.DefineMessage(messageText);
        Message lastSentMessage;

        switch (_messageHandler.GetInteractionType())
        {
            case InteractionType.DownloadVideo:
                lastSentMessage = await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(
                    chatId: chatId,
                    text: $"{char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x231B)}...",
                    cancellationToken: token
                );
                var videoBytes = await _mediaDownloader.DownloadVideoAsync(messageText);
                if (videoBytes is null)
                {
                    lastSentMessage = await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(
                        chatId: chatId,
                        text: "Ошибка при скачивании видео.\nПопробуйте еще раз!",
                        cancellationToken: token
                    );
                    break;
                }

                var videoStream = new MemoryStream(videoBytes);
                lastSentMessage = await bot.SendVideoAsync(
                    chatId: chatId,
                    video: new InputFile(videoStream),
                    cancellationToken: token
                );
                await videoStream.DisposeAsync();
                break;
            case InteractionType.Start:
                lastSentMessage = await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(
                    chatId: chatId,
                    text: "Доброго времени суток!\nНапишите ссылку на песню с YouTube ниже)",
                    cancellationToken: token
                );
                break;
            case InteractionType.Other:
                lastSentMessage = await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(
                    chatId: chatId,
                    text: "Непонятная команда!",
                    cancellationToken: token
                );
                break;
        }
    }

    private Task HandleErrorAsync(ITelegramBotClient bot, Exception exception, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var errorMessage = exception switch
        {
            ApiRequestException apiRequestException
                => $"Telegramm API Error: \n[{apiRequestException.ErrorCode}]\n{apiRequestException.Message}",
            _ => exception.ToString()
        };

        Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
   ```

   }

2.Код основного класса, где собирается и запускается приложение:

```
using Telegram.Bot;
using TestTgBot;


ITelegramBotClient botClient = new TelegramBotClient("мой токен");
MessageHandler messageHandler = new MessageHandler();
MediaDownloader mediaDownloader = new MediaDownloader(@"D:\delete\", 30*60);

var bot = new TgBotService(botClient, messageHandler, mediaDownloader);
await bot.StartBot();
Console.ReadLine();
```

3.Код класса, который скачивает видео:

```
using MediaToolkit;
using MediaToolkit.Model;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using TestTgBot.Exceptions;
using VideoLibrary;

namespace TestTgBot;

public class MediaDownloader
{
    private readonly string _directory;
    private readonly int _timeLimit;
    
    public MediaDownloader(string directory, int timeLimit)
    {
        _directory = directory;
        _timeLimit = timeLimit;
    }
    
    public async Task<byte[]?> DownloadVideoAsync(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            var service = Client.For(YouTube.Default);
            var video = await service.GetVideoAsync(url);

            if (video is null)
            {
                throw new DownLoadVideoFailureException(url);
            }
        
            var bytes = await video.GetBytesAsync();
            return bytes;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Используйте [Threading](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-threading-python/klass-thread-modulja-threading/)

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn казалось бы, при чем здесь Python?

Comment: @aepot я вчера какой-то рассеянный был, не заметил)

Comment: Да я тоже думал через треды, но мне кажется должно быть задумано более простое решение такой задачи самими авторами, а то получается, что библиотека не рабочая. Люди вроде пользуются ей уже давно и должны были заметить, да и в документации ничего такого не видел, а там по идее должно быть расписано как полностью рабочий код написать, а не демку какую-то, с обрезанным функционалом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На шарпах еще не пробовал но на питоне сделал поллер, который слушает телеграмм и передает все запросы в очередь. Далее эти запросы выполняются. Это позволило не останавливать программу. Думаю на шарпах можно сделать так же, даже лучше, так как в шарпах это еще и многопоточно можно сделать